# Problems debugging after installing Silverlight update

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010

I made the mistake of downloading the latest Silverlight runtime so that I could watch a video on Channel 9.  Well now Visual Studio 2010 says it cannot debug Silverlight.  The message it gives me is this:

> Unable to start debugging. The Silverlight Developer Runtime is not installed. Please install a matching version.

What is it talking about and where to I get this so called "matching version".

Comment: I just installed Silverlight 5 Tools (without uninstalling Silverlight 5) and restarted Visual Studio and it worked.  Make your comment into an answer and I'll give you the little green checkmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by uninstalling Silverlight 5 in the control panel and installing the [Silverlight 5 Tools](http://www.silverlight.net/downloads).